How do i auto-order jobs but not auto-run them in Control-M?
How do i make it so that CTM would automatically order a set of the same jobs everyday, but hold them ? The ordered jobs should not be run as they will be run manually.
I ran through a bunch of articles and forums but could not find one that holds the jobs. They schedule them, but their jobs run automatically. I would like the jobs remain ordered but not running.

What you are looking for is the 'confirm' option. With confirm enabled on a job, it will be ordered in as per normal scheduling criteria but will remain waiting for a manual confirm before kicking off.
